# How to present appropriate viewcontroller with navigation stack when launching from remote notification

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My goal: When a user launches the app by responding to a remote notification,

1. The user should be presented with appropriate viewcontroller
2. The viewcontroller should have navigation stack identical to what the viewcontroller would have had when the user manually accessed it.

My configuration:
[image]

- `HomeViewController: UITabBarController` is the root. Each tab has `UINavigationController`.
- `ConversationGroupTableViewController: UITableViewController` is at the fourth tab and displays the list of conversation groups.
- `ConversationGroupDetailViewController: UITableViewController` is loaded from `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` in `ConversationGroupTableViewController`. It displays the list of messages in that conversation group.

Example case: User is notified that a new message has arrived. When the user launches the app by responding to remote notification, the user should be presented with an instance of `ConversationGroupDetailViewController` that has `ConversationGroupTableViewController` and `HomeViewController` in its navigation stack so that the user can press back buttons to reach them.

Code so far:
in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)    
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    if let notificationDictionary = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
        instantiateViewControllerFromNotification(notificationDictionary)
    }
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func instantiateViewControllerFromNotification(notificationDictionary: NSDictionary) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    initialViewController.selectedIndex = 3

    let navigationController = initialViewController.viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController
    let detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ConversationGroupDetailViewController") as! ConversationGroupDetailViewController

    navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
    navigationController.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: false)
}
```

I think I'm moving onto right track, but I just can't seem to figure out exactly how to do this. I would appreciate any help!

Edit:
I've done more experimentations and updated the code. This code does what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

@Harfangk

Call this method after delay of 1 second. because you are pushing controller while initiating application.

```
func instantiateViewControllerFromNotification(notificationDictionary: NSDictionary) {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UITabBarController
  initialViewController.selectedIndex = 3

  let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController().viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController
  let tableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ConversationGroupTableViewController") as! ConversationGroupTableViewController
  let detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ConversationGroupDetailViewController") as! ConversationGroupDetailViewController

  navigationController.pushViewController(tableViewController, animated: false) 
  navigationController.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: @harfangk Have you check this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the issue was not the delay but getting the correct instance of each viewcontrollers. I got it working and updated the code.